# Cabal preprocessing symbols

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell: Correct practice to specify version in source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857710/haskell-correct-practice-to-specify-version-in-source)

Is it any way to export cabal metadata to my code? With autotools, I define, for example, program version in `configure.ac` and get it as define for my code. In cabal, currently, I have to mantain program version in two places -- in .cabal and in `--version`. Any elegant solutions?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857710/haskell-correct-practice-to-specify-version-in-source/9857861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this with a shell session:

```
~ $ cd /tmp/
/tmp $ mkdir test
/tmp $ cd test/
/tmp/test $ cabal init
Package name? [default: test] 
Package version? [default: 0.1.0.0] 
Please choose a license:
 * 1) (none)
   2) GPL-2
   3) GPL-3
   4) LGPL-2.1
   5) LGPL-3
   6) BSD3
   7) MIT
   8) PublicDomain
   9) AllRightsReserved
  10) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: (none)] 
Author name? [default: Joachim Breitner] 
Maintainer email? [default: mail@joachim-breitner.de] 
Project homepage URL? 
Project synopsis? 
Project category:
 * 1) (none)
   2) Codec
   3) Concurrency
   4) Control
   5) Data
   6) Database
   7) Development
   8) Distribution
   9) Game
  10) Graphics
  11) Language
  12) Math
  13) Network
  14) Sound
  15) System
  16) Testing
  17) Text
  18) Web
  19) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: (none)] 
What does the package build:
   1) Library
   2) Executable
Your choice? 2
Include documentation on what each field means (y/n)? [default: n] 

Guessing dependencies...

Generating LICENSE...
Warning: unknown license type, you must put a copy in LICENSE yourself.
Generating Setup.hs...
Generating test.cabal...

Warning: no synopsis given. You should edit the .cabal file and add one.
You may want to edit the .cabal file and add a Description field.
/tmp/test $ vim *.cabal
/tmp/test $ cat *.cabal
name:                test
version:             0.1.0.0
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Joachim Breitner
maintainer:          mail@joachim-breitner.de
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

executable test
  main-is: Main.hs
  build-depends:       base ==4.5.*

/tmp/test $ echo 'main = return ()' > Main.hs
/tmp/test $ cabal configure && cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring test-0.1.0.0...
Warning: The 'license-file' field refers to the file 'LICENSE' which does not
exist.
Building test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'test' for test-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist/build/test/test-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/test/test ...
/tmp/test $ find dist/
dist/
dist/package.conf.inplace
dist/setup-config
dist/build
dist/build/autogen
dist/build/autogen/Paths_test.hs
dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h
dist/build/test
dist/build/test/test-tmp
dist/build/test/test-tmp/Main.o
dist/build/test/test-tmp/Main.hi
dist/build/test/test
/tmp/test $ grep -i version dist/build/autogen/Paths_test.hs
    version,
import Data.Version (Version(..))
version :: Version
version = Version {versionBranch = [0,1,0,0], versionTags = []}
/tmp/test $ echo 'import Paths_test' > Main.hs
/tmp/test $ echo 'main = print version' >> Main.hs
/tmp/test $ cabal build
Building test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'test' for test-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 2] Compiling Paths_test       ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_test.hs, dist/build/test/test-tmp/Paths_test.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist/build/test/test-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/test/test ...
/tmp/test $ ./dist/build/test/test
Version {versionBranch = [0,1,0,0], versionTags = []}
```

(TL;DR: cabal generates a module called `Paths_<pkgname>` that defines a constant `version :: Version`.)